# Smooth scrollbar - what executes scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I've implemented [Smooth scrollbar](https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/) on my page and it works pretty nice but I also want to add some transition effect in the scrolling content. Basically I wanted do it on a scroll event but I don't know how smooth scrollbar works and what object executes on scroll event. I've checked that #my-scrollbar is not doing that:

```js
$("#my-scrollbar").on("scroll", function () {
 console.log("scroll"); //not working
});
```

What causes on scroll event? Or is there another way to do some additional effects without checking on scroll event?

EDIT: I'm pasting my code (I'm using React.js) to explain a little bit more.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Smooth scrollbar with parallax</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="my-scrollbar">
            <div id="root"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./website/App.css";
import App from "./website/App";
import Scrollbar from "smooth-scrollbar";

Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector("#my-scrollbar"));

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";


class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       $(document).on("scroll", function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });

        const h1posX = 64;
        const h1posY = 64;
        $("#section2 h1").css({ transform: `translate(${h1posX}px,${h1posY}px)` });
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
            const distance = window.scrollY;
            console.log(distance);
            if (distance <= $("#section1").outerHeight() / 2) document.querySelector(".container2").style.transform = `translateY(${distance * 1.15}px)`;
            $("#box2").css({ transfrom: `translateY(${distance}px)` });
            $("#section2 h1").css({ transform: `translate(${distance * 0.15}px,${h1posY}px)` });
        }); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <main>
                    <header>
                        <div className="container2">
                            <h3>Hello world!</h3>
                            <p>Scroll to see smooth scrolling</p>
                        </div>
                    </header>

                    <div id="section1">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div id="section2">
                        <h1>Dolor sit amet</h1>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #eee;
    z-index: -1;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #0056a7, #165fa3, #477aaa);
    animation: fadeIn 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

#section1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 5rem;
    background: transparentize(#47aa79, 0);
}

#section2 {
    display: flex;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #477aaa;
    color: #eee;

    h1 {
        position: absolute;
        transition: all 0.1s linear;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the `event` handled to the callback function as argument and use it.

```
$("#my-scrollbar").on("scroll", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

The event will return properties object and you can use any event property you need like: `event.type`

Here is a DEMO: https://codepen.io/aslami/pen/oNBJvpq

Comment: Still nothing appears in browser console.

Comment: Did you try scrolling down to the page? If the scroller doesn't appear it means your document content is less than the viewport. Add more content to the page to make it scrollable. I tested before answering your question.

Comment: I've got enough content to make it scrollable. Scrollbar appears and, as I said before, smooth scrolling works pretty good. I suppose that it happens because default scrolling is overwritten by another object which executes scrolling than `$(window)` or `$("my-scrollbar")` but I don't know what causes scrolling and how to check it.

Comment: Set a fixed height for "my-scrollbar" div and set CSS "overflow: scroll"

Comment: You needed to log the scroll event object and that is solution I answered. Try it with $(document) if you want to test it.

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'Set a fixed height for "my-scrollbar"'? Do I need to set for example 100% height or 100vh?

Comment: Any height just to make the DIV scrollable for your testing purpose.

Comment: Nothing has changed. Maybe I'll edit post and paste my whole code to show how it looks like

Comment: Thanks for demo but in your example there isn't implemented smooth scrollbar and for me it is important to determine what causes scrolling using this library.